# How to deploy a Flask app with factory function for application creation

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have managed to deploy a singleton flask application with wsgi and apache2 using the following configurations in the .wsgi file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/Devrupt/")

from Devrupt import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'

activate_this = '/var/www/Devrupt/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

My Apache2 .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName devrupt.com
        ServerAdmin lui@devrupt.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Devrupt/devrupt.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/Devrupt/Devrupt/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/Devrupt/Devrupt/static
        <Directory /var/www/Devrupt/Devrupt/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I deploy a Flask application with factory function for application creation?

Flask Application with factory function structure:

```
| - Devrupt
    | - Devrupt
        |- app/
            |- templates/
            |- static/  
            |- main/
                |- __init__.py
                |- errors.py
                |- forms.py
                |- views.py
            |- __init__.py      # Factory Function
            |- models.py
        |- migrations/          # Contains the database migrations scripts
        |- tests/               # Where unit tests are written
            |- __init__.py
            |- test*.py
        |- venv/                # Contains the python virtual environment
        |- requirements.txt     # List package dependencies so that it is easy to regenerate an identical virtual environment on a diff machine
        |- config.py            # Stores the configuration settings
        |- manage.py            # Launch the application and other applcation tasks

| - devrupt.wsgi
```

[mod_wsgi (Apache)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/) states that "If you don’t have a factory function for application creation but a singleton instance you can directly import that one as application."

app/**init**.py(factory function):

```
# Application Package Constructor
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from config import config

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
moment = Moment()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)

    # Attach Routes and custom error messages here
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)


return app
```

What ammendments do i have to do to enable it to work on a Factory Function Application?

Comment: Why do you need a factory? If you're successfully running as a singleton you're fine. And we can't tell you want you need to change because a factory has nothing to do with directory structure, it's something you define in code. Have you written a factory function? If not, that's where you need to start.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that you have an application object in your `.wsgi` file. This object can be created using a factory function. For example:

```
from Devrupt import application_factory
application = application_factory()
```

It's that easy!
But to really spell it out, modify devrupt.wsgi to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
activate_this = 'var/www/Devrupt/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/")

from Devrupt import create_app
application = create_app('development')
```

Comment: So i have added the code for my Factory Function(app/__init__.py) into the question. How do I add the application object into my .wsgi file?